# Sorting Array order on C

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, ascii

I'm trying to sort this array in order on C and I'm not getting it right. What I'm doing wrong? The sorted array is wrong, it should be displayed in the below order:

```
0: boy 
1: is 
2: right 
3: sitting 
4: The 
5: there.
```

Thank you all!

```
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); 
    int i; 
  
    // Print the given array 
    printf("Given array is\n"); 
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        printf("%d: %s \n", i, arr[i]); 
  
    // Sort the array 
    sort(arr, n); 
  
    // Print the sorted array 
    printf("\nSorted array is\n"); 
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        printf("%d: %s \n", i, arr[i]); 
  
    return 0; 
} 


Output:

   
Sorted array is
The 
boy 
is 
right 
sitting 
there.
```

Comment: In a case-sensitive search `T` sorts before `b`.

Comment: Use `stricmp()` if you want case-insensitive comparison.

Comment: It looks like you want upper case and lower case to be interchangeable (a case insensitive search)  for Windows the furnction is stricmp() and for Unix it is strcasecmp()

Comment: Great to know thank you

Comment: Where is `sort` coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I'm doing wrong?

Nothing. Your code works fine.

A good way to debug this would be to print the value of, say, the first character of each word. That would show you the value of 'T', 'b', etc., and you'd see that A-Z have lower values than a-z.

Looking at it another way, if you want the words to print in the order given at the top of your question, you're going to have to sort them so that they're *not* in ASCII order. You'll need to come up with a `compare` function that considers 'T' and 't' to be the same.

Comment: I understand that "Nothing" is a valid answer to that question but he did give an expected output so it would help future people looking at this question if you would offer a suggestion of how to achieve the expected output.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I've added a paragraph that does exactly that, but the OP's big problem is simply that he/she didn't understand *why* the output happened. Knowing that 't' is different from 'T' should help significantly.